# Issue with cache on custom chrome tab: Amazon pay

Tags: android, google-chrome, cookies, amazon-pay

I am implementing amazon pay on android using web URL and facing this issue.

I am using custom chrome tab and after one payment it start showing error "Please enable cookies to continue"

I have tried to resolve this by using

- CookieManager [Usauly for Webview]
- TrustedWebActivity

[image]

Comment: Is this for a native Android app integration or for a mobile web integration?  If this is for a native app, Amazon Pay should be implemented using secured web views.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it appears that the page is getting opened in a Chrome webview and not the Chrom Custom Tab. AmazonPay for Native Android will not work on Chrome webviews.

Pls check the code once.

Comment: Yes it happens with both chrome and custom chrome tab.